# Azure, App service, the site show the message "This web app has been successfully created" after deployment although localy the site appears

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I'm using VS 2013 and SDK 2.2 to deploy to App Services, the site opens in it's address and show the message "This web app has been successfully created".

Like when there is no code in the cloud app. although I can enter the App Service Editor, and see the code is there.

Localy I run the site and it show the Home/index page, but not in the cloud.
It was fine before, until I remove the web project and created another one with the same name instead.

Hope all this clause help to solve..

[image: Local vs Cloud]

Comment: What do you mean, when you say you *enter the App Service Editor" ? Have you opened a console window via kudu and verified all your files are uploaded?

Comment: It's not Kudu, there is another option next to Kudu, called, App serviceEditor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I try to redeploy, the SDK assumed some files are already exists and did not reload them.
They were probably corrupted.

The solution was to delete the complete deplyment, the wwroot directory and redeploy.